# return percentage in chart.js (v2+) legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, chart.js2

[Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) 2+ does not return percentages for legend items in pie charts anymore.

I am storing the legend in the separate item in my html named `#legend`. Then I set it's `innerHTML` to `myPieChart.generateLegend()`. It returns both the color and name but I'd like to be able to override this HTML template to also return percentages, so the output goes from looking like:

> - A
> - B
> - C

to:

> - A (13%)
> - B (50%)
> - C (37%)

I used to do it with the `legendTemplate` argument but it does not seem to work anymore:

```
legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%> (<%=segments[i].value%>%)<%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
```

Comment: Please provide context and code to your question, so others can benefit from it as well; how are you currently generating your legend text? What have you tried so far?

Comment: hi, thank you for your response, see my update

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) v2 has a completely different API than earlier versions. You should read the new [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) carefully before upgrading (and then having to wonder what wen't wrong).

The fundamental changes (related to your question) are:

- `legendTemplate` and `segments` are not available anymore. You should instead use [`legendCallback`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-common-chart-configuration) (in `options`) to override the default legend implementation. Here's what the documentation says about this callback:

> Function to generate a legend. Receives the chart object to generate a legend from. Default implementation returns an HTML string.

- The data you used from `segments` are available in the `chart` parameter (i.e. your actual chart object) of your `legendCallback` function here: `chart.data.datasets[0].data`.
- Now that we know where to get our required data from, we can loop through `chart.data.datasets[0].data` to collect the values and append them to the legend HTML string.
- Then we can simply call `myPieChart.generateLegend()`, which will invoke our `legendCallback`.

Complete example:

```
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: d,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                    return data.labels[tooltipItem.index] + ' (' + data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index] + '%)';
                }
            }
        },
        legendCallback: function (chart) {
            var text = [];
            text.push('<ul class="' + chart.id + '-legend">');

            var data = chart.data;
            var datasets = data.datasets;
            var labels = data.labels;

            if (datasets.length) {
                for (var i = 0; i < datasets[0].data.length; ++i) {
                    text.push('<li><span style="background-color:' + datasets[0].backgroundColor[i] + '"></span>');
                    if (labels[i]) {
                        text.push(labels[i] + ' (' + datasets[0].data[i] + '%)');
                    }
                    text.push('</li>');
                }
            }
            text.push('</ul>');
            return text.join('');
        },
        legend: {
            // since you're providing your own legend
            display: false,
        },                
    }
});

var legend = myPieChart.generateLegend();
document.getElementById("legend").innerHTML = legend;
```

For purposes of completeness, I've also added the same `TEXT (PERCENTAGE%)` template on the tooltips labels (which similarly to legends, provide their own callbacks for overriding default implementations).

I would also suggest browsing through the actual Chart.js source code, in particular having a look at `legendCallBack`, `generateLegend()`, etc, to gain a better understanding of how things work under the hood.

Comment: it works!! thank you so much for all your help so far!

Comment: Glad I could help.